# First attempt to play any audio after boot results in 30-second delay

Tags: windows-7, audio, boot, delay

For some time now, my laptop has had an odd problem with sound. The first time I attempt to play any kind of sound after booting the computer, there is a delay of approximately 30 seconds before the sound plays. It only happens once after boot. It happens regardless of how soon after boot I attempt to play sound (e.g., 2 minutes or 2 hours), or which application I attempt to use.

The behavior is different for different applications, however. In desktop applications like iTunes, clicking the "Play" button causes the application to block for ~30 seconds, then playback begins at the start of the stream. On the web (in Google Chrome), streaming audio and video plays silently for the first ~30 seconds, then suddenly starts having sound at the current position (not the beginning the stream).

To be clear, my audio/video is never out of sync -- either everything is delayed for 30 seconds and it fixes itself (e.g., imagine a very long I/O operation), or the video and computer run smoothly but are just silent for the first 30 seconds. In any case, after the initial delay, I don't experience any further problems until I reboot my computer.

Windows lists my sound card as "IDT High Definition Audio CODEC". I tried the IDT web site, but it does not offer drivers for end users and refers me to Dell's driver download site (I already have the latest driver from the Dell site installed). I ran Microsoft's FixIt program to troubleshoot audio and it didn't find any problems (e.g., the audio services are enabled, drivers are installed, etc.). I examined the Event Viewer and didn't see anything related to audio. What else should I check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the Audiodg.exe scanning all .CAT files from

`C:\Windows\System32\catroot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}`

The more updates or MUI packs you have installed, the longer it takes for Windows to validate them. I've already reported this to MSFT years ago, but I have no idea if they will ever fix it.

Comment: And a quick word of caution to anyone attempting to solve this problem by simply deleting the offending directory: Don't. :-(

Comment: never do this. This breaks a lot. Remove all unused MUI packs and remove replaced Windows Updates like older cumulative IE updates.

Answer (score 1):

I found the actual cause and a couple of workarounds.

**Cause**:

The codec `l3codeca.acm` does not have an embedded signature, and hence Windows needs to look up the proper signature from catroot. If you have a lot of patches in your system, then catroot will be large and the lookup can take a long time.

The whole startup delay is caused by only this single codec(!). This problem seems to be present all the way back to when l3codeca was introduced in Windows.

**Workarounds**:

**1.** Disable `l3codeca.acm` from the registry:

In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32` find the key with the value `C:\Windows\System32\l3codeca.acm` and rename it to something else.
Example `C:\Windows\System32\l3codeca.acm_disabled`.

**2.** Disable the signature check for audio codecs (potential security risk):

In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Audio` add `DWORD` `DisableProtectedAudioDG` with value 1.