# The process audiodg.exe scans catroot and hogs IO

Tags: windows-7

Audio takes maybe 5 to 10 minutes to start working after booting opening resource monitor shows that audiodg.exe has tons of IO on

`C:\Windows\System32\catroot{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}`

see screenshot:

[image: here]

I have about 16,000 items in this folder so it would take a long time to scan it, especially since it's probably random access IO.

What can I remove to reduce the size of the folder or how can I stop audiodg.exe from scanning the folder?

I have tried following the steps in [Microsoft Support:- Disk Cleanup Wizard addon lets users delete outdated Windows updates on Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2852386)
 to reduce the number of files in catroot, but I do not have the option of 'On the Disk Cleanup tab, select Windows Update Cleanup, and then click OK.' as mentioned in the article. I clicked on the run as administrator, and the option was still not there. I thought that maybe I didn't I have the plugin. I tried installing the plugin available in the article, but it said I already had it.

This is similar to this [Superuser Question:- First attempt to play any audio after boot results in 30-second delay](https://superuser.com/questions/584746/first-attempt-to-play-any-audio-after-boot-results-in-30-second-delay) and I wanted to continue the discussion there, but the moderator asked me to post a new question.

### Update

There is something seriously wrong with my computer. My hypothesis is that when laptop was given to me, it was install with ALL the language packs and I did not notice. As a result, some updates related to language packs would take much longer (for instance IE). At some point I was probably to impatient to wait for the machine to update everything when shutting down, and forced the shut down. This corrupted the machine.

The reason for this guess is:

- When I go to turn windows features on/off , it is empty

  - I've tried to install the update readiness tool as described in [how to fix empty turn windows features on or off](https://superuser.com/questions/548332/how-to-fix-empty-turn-windows-features-on-or-off/996583#996583)
- When I try to remove the language packs, they always fails (I made sure to try the leaf packs first)

Comment: Posted a couple workarounds for this problem here: https://superuser.com/a/1701592/89010

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that I discovered several years ago and submitted to Microsoft.

To get the update cleanup option, you have to [install](https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/A/3/2A3FD850-E45F-47D4-AFF8-8048333CBA7D/Windows6.1-KB2852386-v2-x64.msu) the [Update KB2852386](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2852386). When you now run Disk Cleanup you see the option to cleanup old Windows Updates.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I already had that cleanup plugin installed and it still did not give me the option to cleanup old windows updates.

Comment: in this case, there are no old updates that can be removed.

Comment: I'm curious to understand why a service [seemingly made to provide exclusively audio support](https://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/audiodg.exe.html) and sound-related features needs to read the history of Windows updates? I don't see the connection (and Google didn't help)

Comment: audio doesn't scan the history. The more updates you have installed, the more [CAT files you have in catroot folder which windows has to validate](https://superuser.com/a/584788/174557). If you remove replaced updates, it will be faster and the cpu usage will be smaller @mins

Comment: I was a bit wrong, it seems `%Systemroot%\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}` is the repository containing the signatures of system files, to be used by the file protection system, not the KB updates. Still is there a reason audiodg process takes an extra step to scan these signatures? (compared, for example, to opening a command shell with administrator rights which doesn't do this scan). Is it because it works with elevated privileges and needs to be more careful with what it calls? What can explain accessing a signature for a given file is not direct but sequential?

Comment: @mins I can only guess why and I think it is because of DRM, to avoid that system files get modified and can used to copy DRM protected music.